# How to find a spam link?

Tags: admin, spam

While analyzing my site I found many requests is done to external link to "friendsit.net" so I installed string locator plugin and tried to search all source files but I found nothing , I also tried to search the database but I found many results like this in select queries

```
LIKE '%friendsit.net%'
```

how to find this link and remove ?

The external link to an image in the above site but does not exists !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try a search from the Posts (Admin) screen? (And also the Pages (Admin) screen?

And sometimes a googles of your site might find it: use something like

```
search-term site:example.com
```

...depends on how current the googles are for your site. But sometimes works well.

**Added**

To answer your question/comment: Remember that there is no 'source code' (as such) for a page content (assuming you found the text via a search via Admin, Page). Only the page content as shown in the editor (via Admin, Page) that needs to be changed. (Look at Text mode.)

Now, it is possible that there is some hack of your theme/plugins (if you found the text via the googles), so you should carefully look everywhere and update/change everything: credentials (host, ftp, WP admin-level users); update WP/themes/plugins from repository; check for code in custom functions.php files and any Child Themes; and manually look for bad files (including hidden) in all site folders via FTP; remove unused and old/not-updated-lately themes/plugins.

See my post about 'de-hacking' a site with details: https://securitydawg.com/recovering-from-a-hacked-wordpress-site/  . I have successfully used this process to clean up sites.

Comment: found it in 3 pages, how I get to the source code of these pages ?

Comment: See added info in my answer.